# Create array from variable name

Tags: php, sql, arrays

Im trying to create an array from a variable name. I want to get the information from an sql table and hold that information in an array, however I get an error saying "cannot use [] for reading". Why?

```
<?php
// SQL Selection CurrentProduct Attributes
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $current_product_name";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
${current_product_name ._array[]} = $row; // add the row in to the array
}
${current_product_name ._length} = count({$current_product_name . _array});
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't let the trees hide the forest:

```
$foo = []; // OK (create empty array with the PHP/5.4+ syntax)
$foo[] = 10; // OK (append item to array)
echo $foo[0]; // OK (read one item)
echo $foo[]; // Error (what could it possibly mean?)
```

The [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) notation expects **strings** (either literals or variables):

```
$current_product_name = 'Jimmy';
${$current_product_name . '_array'}[] = 33;
var_dump($Jimmy_array);
```

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  int(33)
}
```

Said that, your approach looks like a terrific way to produce unmaintainable code. Why not an array with a known name?

```
$products[$current_product_name][] = $row;
```

Comment: Thank you! First for the answer and then for the suggestion!